# PHP PDO mySQL query create table if not exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, create-table

Using PHP PDO query to execute a mySQL query. The query is made up of a multitude of information inputted from foreach(); so I have echo'd out the sql query. The problem lies here but I cannot see it.

This is the output of `$sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page` (
  `page_ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200),
  `subtitle` TEXT,
  `content` TEXT,
  `parent` varchar(10),
  `privacy` varchar(1),
  `status` varchar(1),
  `creation` varchar(30)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

FYI the query is executed like this:

```
function createdbtable($table,$fields){
    global $fsdbh;
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (";
    foreach($fields as $field => $type){ $sql.= "`$field` $type,"; }
    $sql = rtrim($sql,',');
    $sql .= ") CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci"; return $sql;
    if($fsdbh->exec($sql) !== false) { return 1; }
}
```

This is the error:

> #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Do you get errors...? Have you checked?

Comment: What is expected and what is actually you are getting?

Comment: #1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Problem listed .  $SQL already shown

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `page` (
`page_ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(200),
`subtitle` TEXT,
`content` TEXT,
`parent` varchar(10),
`privacy` varchar(1),
`status` varchar(1),
`creation` varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (`page_ID`)) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Error was quite explicit:

> Schema Creation Failed: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

You must specify the auto increment key as key.

**edit:**

And for the PHP code, I will go to something like that:

```
function createdbtable($table,$fields)
{
    global $fsdbh;

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table` (";
    $pk  = '';

    foreach($fields as $field => $type)
    {
      $sql.= "`$field` $type,";

      if (preg_match('/AUTO_INCREMENT/i', $type))
      {
        $pk = $field;
      }
    }

    $sql = rtrim($sql,',') . ', PRIMARY KEY (`'.$pk.'`)';

    $sql .= ") CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
    if($fsdbh->exec($sql) !== false) { return 1; }
}
```